# Trouble with ComboBox and calculations

Tags: java, user-interface, combobox

I am trying to use a method to calculate the duration of a trip, using this:

```
  private void updateTripDurationText()
{


    String speed = (String)avgspeedBox.getSelectedItem();
    String dist = (String)distanceText.getText();

    double s = Double.parseDouble(speed);
    double d = Double.parseDouble(dist);
    double durationTime = d/s;
    String dTime = String.format("1%.1f", Double.toString(durationTime));
    durationText.setText(dTime);

   }
```

Although I can run the program, I get an error that involves empty string. The prgram has 3 combo boxes. Where you choose your A and B locations where it will then bring up the distance. I want the third combobox (speed) to calculate the duration as distance/speed then put it into the text box. Where am I going wrong?

This is the action listener:

```
private class ComboBoxListener implements ActionListener
{


  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {

        setCities(destinationBox.getSelectedIndex(),originBox.getSelectedIndex());
     updateDistanceText();
        updateTripDurationText();

   }

 }
```

After separating this into different event handlers I am having a problem with incorrect calculations. The calculation for duration is returning very large values.

Comment: An error that involves empty string? What is the exact error?

Comment: xception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
and at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: This error you are getting because your string is empty and you are trying to convert into number.

Comment: My goal is to make the GUI program be able to change the calculation of distance/duration as you change the comboboxes, I can do this for the destinations, but not for the duration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
String.valueOf(Primitive/Object Reference)
```

Rather than `toString` method so that it will not throw any `NullPointerException` in the case the primitive or object results in `NULL` value. And also for `ComboBox` or `ListBox` use `ItemListener` and override its method `itemStateChanged()`.

Comment: Okay, that worked... sortof. The GUI is all wonky now though and doesn't update instantly whenever I change speed. What would cause this?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a good idea to check if `speed` or `dist` is empty before parsing them with Double.parseDouble.  But then what if some enters "20.2 miles" into the dist box.  It won't be an empty string, but will still throw the NumberFormatException.

```
if ((speed.length() > 0) && (dist.length() > 0)) {
  String speed = (String)avgspeedBox.getSelectedItem();
  // rest of your code...
}
```

Try catching the exception and if caught, let the user know that their input was bad.

```
try {
    if ((speed.length() > 0) && (dist.length() > 0)) {
      String speed = (String)avgspeedBox.getSelectedItem();
      // rest of your code...
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
  // show some kind of warning message
}
```

Comment: They are combo boxes, the textfields are just to put the results and are read only. No direct user input in the program